# VB.NET Webbrowser.Document - what you see is not what you can get

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, dom

My attempts at writing a simple crawler seem to be confounded by the fact that my target webpage (as would appear in the UI browser control, or through a typical browser application) is not completely accessible as an HTMLDocument (due to frames, javascript, etc.)

The code below executes, and the correct webpage (e.g. the one displaying items 50-59) can even be seen in the control, but where I would expect the “next page” hyperlink retrieved to be “...&start=60”, I see something else – the one corresponding to opening the first catalog page “...&start=10”.
What is odd, is that if I press the button a second time, I DO get what I’m looking for.  Even odder to me, if I inserted a MsgBox, say right after I’ve looped to wait until  WebBrowserReadyState.Complete, then I get what I’m looking for.

```
Private Sub ButtonGo_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonGo.Click
    'start at this URL
    'e.g. http://www.somewebsite.com/properties?l=Dallas+TX&co=US&start=50
    catalogPageURL = TextBoxInitialURL.Text
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(catalogPageURL)
    While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    'Locate the URL associated with the NEXT>> hyperlink
    Dim allLinksInDocument As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
    Dim strNextPgLink As String = ""
    For Each link As HtmlElement In allLinksInDocument
        If link.GetAttribute("className") = "next" Then
            strNextPgLink = link.GetAttribute("href")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I’ve googled around enough to try things like using a WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
event, but that still didn’t work.  I’ve tried inserting sleep commands.

I’ve avoided using WebClient and regular expressions, the way I would have ordinarily done this, because I’m convinced using the DOM will be easier for other things I have planned down the road, and I’m aware of HTML Agility Pack but not ambitious enough to learn it.  Because it seems there has to be a simple way to have this dang webbrowser.document object synchronized with the stuff you can actually see.

If this is because of javascript, is there a way I can tell the webbrowser to just execute them all?

First question on the forum, looking forward to more (smarter ones hopefully)

Comment: Are you looking just to extract links? If so, try HTML Agility Pack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks, am looking into HTML Agility Pack, but I do want to use the WebBrowser because eventually I will want to invoke jscripts; also the simplicity of the GetElementById and GetAttribute is appealing.

Answer (score 0):

Be warned when using webbrowser1.Document or something similar - you will not get 'raw html'

Example: (assume wbMain is a webbrowser control)

```
    RTB_RawHTML.Text = wbMain.DocumentText
    Try
         RTB_BodyHTML.Text = wbMain.Document.Body.OuterHtml
    Catch
         debugMessage("Body tag not found.")
    End Try
```

in this example, the code in the body tag as displayed in the body tag portion of RTB_RawHTML will NOT perfectly match the html as displayed in RTB_BodyHTML. Accessing it through (yourwebbrowserhere).Document.Body.OuterHtml appears to 'clean' it somewhat as opposed to the 'raw' html as retreived by (yourwebbrowserhere).DocumentText

This was a problem for me when i was making a web scraper, as it would continually throw me off - sometimes i would try to match a tag and it would find it, and other times it wouldnt even though i was sure it was there. The reason was that i was trying to match the raw html, but i needed to match the 'cleaned' html.

Im not sure if this will help you isolate the problem or not - for me it did.